# MySQL - How to count entries in one table based on criteria in another table (except when)

Tags: mysql, select

I am trying to do a simple thing and fail...

Basically i want to check how many entries exist in one table based on some values, compared to entries on another table and bring a count of total entries of the first table based on this comparison.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM contacts c
INNER JOIN projects p ON p.ContactId = c.ContactId 
WHERE c.TypeofContactId = '2' 
AND p.CategoryId NOT IN (2,5)
```

What does this mean? I got 2 tables, one has contacts that i had with customers, and the other is projects created based on those contacts.

The **c.TypeofContactId** is what type of contact was it (phone, emails, etc)

The **p.CategoryId** is the type of project created. There can be 50 types.

The projects are 'attached' to contacts based on the **ContactId**.

I want to count all contacts done for a specific type, but only when the project category was NOT 2 or 5. (so anything else...)

So if it cant find any projects (not 2 or 5 type) for c.type = 2, i should get 0 counts.

What am i doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN p.CategoryId NOT IN (2,5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalCount 
FROM contacts c
INNER JOIN projects p ON p.ContactId = c.ContactId 
WHERE c.TypeofContactId = '2'
```

When you put the `p.CategoryId NOT IN (2,5)` in the where clause, you will get only those rows that match this criteria.